# Is there a way to get the state of an object on a Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I there anyway to check the state of a canvas object? I've dug through the documentation and can't seem to find anything. I am looking for something like:

```
canvasWidget.getState(node1)
```

I have a bunch of nodes that I want the user to be able to draw lines that connect the nodes, and I want to have the line follow my cursor to sort of animate the creation of the line like my picture below.

To do so, I have a hidden line that I plan on making visible and then I'll change the coordinates to following the cursor.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _"the state of a canvas object"_?

Comment: hidden, disabled, or normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called `itemcget`

Syntax is

```
state = canvas.itemcget(canvasItem,'state')
```